# Restar nro directo en consulta sql Querybuilder Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Tengo una consulta creada con QueryBuilder, es un `update` y lo que quiero es que un campo, solo redusca en 1.

```
DB::table('Medicos')
    ->where('ID','=',$request->medico)
    ->update(['fichas'=>'fichas-1']);
```

No se si me explico... es algo asi. De otra forma, tendria que hacer una consulta para saber cuantos tiene, restarlo en la lógica y luego modificar el dato en la base de datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puede hacerlo asi

[DB:raw()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-expressions):

```
DB::table('Medicos')
->where('ID','=',$request->medico)
->update(['fichas' => DB::raw('fichas + 1')]);
```

[increment()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#increment-and-decrement):

```
DB::table('Medicos')
->where('ID','=',$request->medico)
->increment('fichas', 1);
```